# Which streaming API to implement in Cocoa/iOS/MacOSX?

Tags: ios, macos, cocoa, io, stream

There are a couple of streaming functions and/or classes in iOS/MacOSX. If I wanted to implement my own custom stream i.e. some object that either provides or consumes sequential bytes of data, which of the following API's would be best to use?

- Unix **file descriptors** (int)

  - No way to implement custom file descriptor?
- **FILE***

  - Use funopen to implement own stream.
  - C-level API, not a lot of Cocoa actually uses this. E.g. cannot bridge this to NSInputStream.
  - Data can be consumed by your own code
- **CGDataProviderRef**, **CGDataConsumerRef**

  - Allows both sequential and direct access read implementations.
  - Used by CoreGraphics but nothing else.
  - Data cannot be consumed from your own code
- **NSInputStream**, **NSOutputStream**

  - Used by a lot of Cocoa e.g. XML, JSON parsing
  - Doc allows subclassing, but in practice subclassing is tricky because of asynchronous use.
  - Data can be consumed from your own code

It would seem NSInputStream/NSOutputStream is the ideal "Cocoa" way of implementing your own stream. However I'm not sure how to implement an App Store-friendly i.e. no overriding of hidden methods (see e.g. http://bjhomer.blogspot.com.au/2011/04/subclassing-nsinputstream.html), subclass of NSInputStream, and either:

(a) make a synchronous-only stream (how do I know whether a particular Cocoa API would consume streams asynchronously and thus not work with my synchronous-only stream?) or

(b) make an asynchronous stream?